# EasyAdminBundle: configuration problem in production environment

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I've been using EasyAdminBundle in a symfony 4 application generated using flex (`composer req admin`) for quite some time now. Recently I added a few entities to the existing EasyAdmin-configuration. In my development environment they show up as excepted, but a soon as I switch to production these new entries are gone. I already cleared/warmed the cache, checked for production specific configuration files, read the symfony docs several times, watched the easy admin tutorial series on KnpUniversity and even deployed to a second server. ;-)

There must be some kind of production specific configuration I'm totally missing. Does anyone have a hint where to look?

I really appreciate any idea! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "new entries are gone"? The new "entity classes" are not listed? The CRUD for these new classes are not available?

Comment: I mean that they are not listet in the navigation on the left hand side.